# Update Custom fields 30 Days after

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am having trouble finding a solution. I am using ACF5.

I would like a field to automatically change its value 7 days after the post author has chosen a value.
I am using a select field (Featured) with 2 values (Featured, Not Featured).

If you have a solution with a different type a field that would work too.

I found this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85606/124674 However, I do not know how to to use it.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so you need two things:

a) you need to know when user modified that field.

Therefore you have to add some `modified` date field where you put a timestamp of last change of the `featured` field. Additionally if you have a lot of posts you may have a `user_modified` field "flag" to mark specific entries as needing attention.

b) you need to have a cron task which runs every minute / hour

This task would scan the `wp_postmeta` table in certain time intervals. When it finds the field which was modified by user and the modification date is older than XX days then you switch the value to the desired one.

I know that this is an overall overview and you still have a lot of small tiny details to figure out but those depend on your scenario.